# CSS : How do fix W3 Validation Error caused by Genesis theme

Tags: html, css, validation, genesis

I am new to this board so please be sympathetic about my issue.

After verifying my website vocaloid.de/Wordpress/ with the [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fvocaloid.de%2FWordpress%2F&profile=css3&warning=no&vextwarning=true&lang=en), I got multiple parsing and value errors. I tried disabling all plugins except the one that causes the css failure. The errors seem to come from the [html source code](http://vocaloid.de/Wordpress/). I would like to know how to fix this. Probably this caused by a wrong coding. I'm not sure..

I hope that I can learn troubleshooting as soon as possible to help others.

Comment: to validate 100% is impossible since I don't know what html source code you've got. anyway, if you use bootstrap there will be <hr> and should be changed into <hr /> as well as <br> and many other things and of course this takes too much time to be discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to submit in w3c validator and check what source in error type. Then you make it correct one by one. Check all the checkboxes there and find the clean or tidy source, copy that if it can help you.